# Terraform - Quota limits for BigQuery API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform

I am looking for a Terraform code sample to set the quota limits for the BigQuery API.

Can someone please provide me with an example if any?

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to do it outside of Terraform?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually possible using the google-beta provider. You can set up the provider and quota like so:

```
variable "region" {
  description = "Google project default region"
}
variable "project_id" {
  description = "Google project id"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_service_usage_consumer_quota_override" "bq_usage_per_day" {
  provider = google-beta
  project = var.project_id
  service = "bigquery.googleapis.com"
  metric = urlencode("bigquery.googleapis.com/quota/query/usage")
  limit = urlencode("/d/project")
  override_value = 1000000
  force = true
}
```

The above would set the quota limit to around 1,000,000 MiB (976.563 GiB)

Comment: I'm looking to set the "per user per day" quota as well. However, what I should put in the limit field is very mysterious and I can't find a reference anywhere. Can you point me to a reference or let me know what the limit field should be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you are not able to set quota limits for the BigQuery API with Terraform. Nonetheless, [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/bigquery_dataset.html) you will find all Google BigQuery resources available for Terraform as a provider.

As documented here, you will find further information regarding the different [quotas and limits presents in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas).

I will also attach how you can request an increase in your quota [here.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota) and how to create [custom cost controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas#controlling_query_costs_using_bigquery_custom_quotas) within BigQuery.

BigQuery custom cost controls enable you to specify a limit on the number of bytes processed per day, in 10 TB increments. (Note, the minimum is 10TB increments, not 1TB).

Finally, as a workaround, you can control cost by following BigQuery’s best practices, as stated [here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#limit_query_costs_by_restricting_the_number_of_bytes_billed)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes , this is really helps to understand more on the BigQuery.                                                                      Thanks a lot.